# Fetch version number from GitHub repository

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble fetching the current version number of my application from a text file in the repository on my GitHub account.

```
def version_check(self):
    # Fetch version number from GitHub repo

    get_version = urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myaccount/myproject/master/VERSION')
    #get_version.read().decode("utf-8") (No terminal output)
    print(get_version.read())
    print(get_version.headers['content-type'])

    #if get_version.read() == version_number:
    #    return True
    #else:
    #    return False
```

I get this terminal output:

```
    b'1.6\n'
    text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

How do I format the output? I believe they are bytes literals but I'm stumped on finding the solution.

Comment: Looks OK to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: Oh sorry it's the b'\n' in the output that is the issue.

Comment: you need to convert from bytes to string and then strip the new line

Comment: if I use get_version.read().decode("utf-8") I just get b' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a "bytes" type value. You need to call the decode function on it to turn it into a string.

```
myBytesVal = myBytesVal.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: No terminal output Just b' '

Comment: The way you're using it in the original code snippet is incorrect. decode does not work in-place, but rather returns the string. So you need to assign that value.

Comment: YES. Thank you.